# how to add a field in openerp for attaching user image

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have created an openerp 7 custom module. I am using eclipse IDE with Python for debugging. I have added 2 fields in my module and is working fine . But on adding the 3rd field am having "xml architecture " error . 
1) I cant resolve this issue
2) Next thing is that I want to add field for image attachment . So that users can attach their image along with their account. How can this be done?

Hopes for suggestion

Comment: would you please provide your error?

Comment: how to add a 3rd field to my module , there is no error but my 3rd field is not visible. I added it in xml as well as python file but cant figure out the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
for image attachment you can add binary field for image


'image': field.binary('Image')
```

Comment: Dont I need to make any other change , like update my xml or import some folder ?

Comment: yes you have to add filed in xml after adding in 'image': fields.binary('Image') in py file

Comment: what will be the xml code, means just as we add simple field or I have to add image widget too?

Comment: you have to add like this <field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_left oe_avatar"/> in xml file

Comment: " Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture! " I am having this error

Comment: can you provide error when you got, it will be very helpful if you give your module.

Comment: james.bale.me@gmail.com here is the my id please send here

Comment: I have sent , do look at it soon

Comment: Have you checked it on openerp-7 because I am still having                    "xml architecture error"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32386/discussion-between-user1576199-and-arsalan-sherwani)